# Does anyone know about Cordova or Ionic mobile app compatibility with Sitecore?

Tags: sitecore-client

Hello my Sitecore Heroes!

Does anyone know about Cordova or Ionic mobile app framework?

I found that Cordova/Ionic are frameworks to create Mobile App which eventually uses webpages and loads webpages in native mobile app. So, does anyone know about Cordova or Ionic mobile app compatibility with Sitecore? Can these framework work with Sitecore website? Will there be any challenge using the Cordova/Ionic mobile app with Sitecore CMS?

Comment: Wondering if you have used ionic app with sitecore jss framework. I would love to hear which route you took for this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is absolotuley no reason why this shouldn't work. As you have full control over the rendered html, css and the JavaScript that you include, you are absolutely free to use cordova or ionic as well, although you have to keep in mind that you will always have to use a experience editor mode in your renderings, but that is always the case

Comment: Thank you Bas for your reply!  This is really helpful. Also looking for someone who has worked on such project where website is on Sitecore CMS and Mobile App on Ionic/Cordova, it will be really helpful if someone share his/her experience on such project.

Comment: if it is helpful for you, could you please mark the answer as "answer"? ;)